# How exactly does Leave Buster work?

Tags: league-of-legends

In the game we are threatened with an almighty 'Leave Buster' feature, which promises to suspend us or anyone else, if the player in question 'frequently leaves matchmade games early'.

Define Frequently. How exactly does leave buster work? How many leaves in how short of a time trigger it? How long are we suspended for?

Comment: Why is this being closed as not constructive?

Comment: @deutschzuid i think because the information I'm asking for isn't apparently public knowledge, and therefor it can be argued the question is somewhat unanswerable.

Comment: IF when you are in champ select, people are acting weird or stupid or talking trash immediately, hell even if you don't like how your team comp looks. Leave before the game starts. You can't be punished by the leave buster for this and you only end up with a time penalty for how long you have to wait til you can play again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[From the unofficial Leave Buster FAQ](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=468889) (click for more details and information)

**How does it work?**

Leaverbuster uses a 'level' system to determine how many games you have left. Essentially if you leave games, you will get a warning. If you continue to leave then your account will be suspended. When your suspension expires, if you continue to leave, you will get a longer suspension. This will continue.

**How does it determine when to ban me?**

The Leaverbuster system has a hidden number that increases and decreases when you AFK/Leave, or when you play a streak of games without leaving/AFKing. This number jumps up much quicker the less games you have played - so if you have only 10 games played 1 leave could get you on leaver level 1. If you have 100 games played, 1 leave might not result in any action - although the hidden number in the background will increase.

**Edit:** To clarify, there is no explicit answer to your question. Riot wouldn't release that information, it could open the system to exploits. The only way to get concrete answers is to talk to people that have been punished by Leave Buster and collect those statistics

Answer (score 3):

The [FAQ](https://support.leagueoflegends.com/entries/20030633-Leaving-Games-The-Leaver-Buster-FAQ) doesn't go into all the details, but says that bans can range from 1 hour to 7 days.

It also states that leaving ranked games is worth double the penalty points of leaving other games.

Anecdote: I believe one of my friends got a 1-hour ban with 4-5 leaves in his first 20ish games on an account, but he straightened up since then and hasn't gotten one since, although he has been forced to leave a couple times.

Answer (score 0):

You can be time banned (banned temporarily for a specified period of time from logging in / queueing) for:

- Idling for around 5 minutes in a game
- Leaving a game
- Leaving during champ select
- Leaving during the "Accept match period" (that's what decline is for)
- Declining a match too much
- Being rude in game, negative attitude, and "cheating."

If you are queue banned for leaving during champ select or for declining too much, you'll still be able to play custom games.

---

To get your LBL (Leave Buster level) down, this is what you need to do:

- Play as much as possible and try not to leave. Be *very* careful about this.
- Show positive attitude within games, and get people to honor you!

Comment: From @An Tran : "It's really annoying for me, and I had to find this list out the hard way. So far I have 4 time 7 day bans, and will do anything to not get permanently banned!

Any help?

Im not actually allowed to play, so I play privately! Sometimes i afk for like 30 seconds..."

Answer (score -1):

I left a game after approximately my 30th game and I got banned for 3 days... So going from that and the story ["Sconipulus" provided](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/114158/12936), it is seemingly random.

Comment: 30 games is not a lot of games. I wouldn't say thats random at all. From my perspective (I've played literally thousands of games) leaving at game 30 isn't any different than leaving at game 10.